# How to get href attributes of a tags in this string?

Tags: c#, html, string

In this string exist number li tag .I want get href attribute of a tags such as this:

```
http://bipardeh94.blogfa.com" target="_blank

http://avaejam.blogfa.com" target="_blank
```

and ...
I want  that do this with  C# .How to done this?
I use this code but this is not complete .

```
int indexStartUl = _codeHtml.IndexOf("<ul");
            int indexEndUl = _codeHtml.IndexOf("</ul>");
            _codeHtml = _codeHtml.Substring(indexStartUl, indexEndUl);
```

Please help.

```
 <ul class="ull">
        <li><a href="http://bipardeh94.blogfa.com" target="_blank">باغ بلور</a><span class="ur">bipardeh94.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">فرهنگی-خبری-علمی</span></li>
        <li><a href="http://avaejam.blogfa.com" target="_blank">هزار نکته </a><span class="ur">avaejam.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds"> يك نكته از هزار نكته  باشد تا بعد </span></li>
        <li><a href="http://prkangavar.blogfa.com" target="_blank">روابط عمومی دانشگاه آزاداسلامی کنگاور</a><span class="ur">prkangavar.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">اخبار دانشگاه</span></li>
        <li><a href="http://bordekhoun.blogfa.com" target="_blank">وبلاگ اطلاع رسانی بردخون</a><span class="ur">bordekhoun.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">اخباروگزارشات وتحلیل ها درباره بردخون</span></li>
        <li><a href="http://mahinvare.blogfa.com" target="_blank">تدوری های نوین</a><span class="ur">mahinvare.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">نظریه های علوم انسانی باید متحول شود</span></li>
        <li><a href="http://zanjanuniversity.blogfa.com" target="_blank">دانشگاه زنجان</a><span class="ur">zanjanuniversity.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">اخبار دانشگاهیان زنجان و دانشگاه آزاد زنجان و سیستم ثبت نام شهردای زنجان </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: add runat='server' , ID=Name To your elements Now , You can access attribute

Comment: You better use a HTML/XML parser or at least Regex instead of working with indices.

Comment: I'm sorry   Ahmed Galal .I want create a web crawler and this is not possible

Comment: Mehrzad Chehraz : Can you write a sample code?

Comment: ahmed-galal : Please  write a sample code.

Comment: Take a look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Selenium` `WebDriver` functionality:

```
IList<IWebElement> lis = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ull > li"));
foreach (IWebElement li in lis) {
    string href = li.GetAttribute("href");
}
```

You find all `WebElements` with `li` tag who are children of `WebElement` with class `ull`, and the iterate over the list and take the href attribute.

Comment: How to download Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: @programmer138200 you can download from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: @programmer138200 installation [guide](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/how-to-download-and-install-selenium.html)

Comment: [Add selenium to VS](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_dotnet_driver_client.jsp)

Comment: Thank you guy.I implement this but  I have an error .Is your for statement is right? In my project  get error !

Comment: @programmer138200 Its `foreach` loop, sorry. Fixed in answer.

Comment: I change this line and worked currently .(  By.CssSelector(".ull > li > a")  ). I have a question , Is possible that  I get source of page with out opening browser?

Comment: @programmer138200 I never did it myself, but there are [options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16196050/5168011) for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

> Html Agility Pack Examples:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

> Links :

[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f

I hope this information will help

Comment: I download and add reference this dll file into my project. Then I use your code in Form2.cs file but get error in this line that cannot access internal constructor htmldocument here =====>>>>>HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

Comment: 1-Download and build the HTMLAgilityPack solution. 
2-In your application, add a reference to HTMLAgilityPack.dll in the HTMLAgilityPack\Debug (or Realease) \bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding

Substring(a,b)

- a : from where you want to start your Substring
- b : what will be the length of the Substring

In your ex you take:

a as start index of ul

b as end index of ul // Error b will be the length from string start to end of ul!

you need to do is:

```
int c = b - a // (will give you the inner text length)

_codeHtml = _codeHtml.Substring(a,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

without any external library or tools, use the following line:

```
var hrefs = html.Split(new[] { "href='" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(o => o.StartsWith("http")).Select(o => o.Substring(0, o.IndexOf("'")));
```

which will give you an array with all the hrefs, like the following result:

```
http://bipardeh94.blogfa.com
http://avaejam.blogfa.com
http://prkangavar.blogfa.com
http://bordekhoun.blogfa.com
http://mahinvare.blogfa.com
http://zanjanuniversity.blogfa.com
```

full example available at: [this .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DrPwT9)