# How can i parse markup text with C#

Tags: c#

I have this text:

```
The family <i>Anatidae</i> includes ducks, geese, and swans,
but <em>not</em> the closely related screamers.
```

How can I parse this text with C#?
I need extract plain text and information about markup to formatting this text in my appliaction.

Thanks.

**UPDATED:**
I can use HtmlAgilityPack to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to build a complete HTML parser?  Or an XML parser?  Or something to find 'i' and 'em' tags in text?

Comment: What s your target format

Comment: I think I need easist way: something to find 'i' and 'em' tags in text

And tags predefined before (like i and em).

I have idea only read string symbol by symbol... but may be is there more ellegant way.

Comment: You could write a helper function which did a search and optional replace on a set of target format codes. Input would be the markup codes `List<string> codes = new List<string>{ "i", "em"};` and your text.

Comment: If you want parse HTML and Get attributes . You can use link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835830/how-to-get-href-attributes-of-a-tags-in-this-string/34835902#34835902

Comment: `I need extract plain text` <-- this part is clear, you need to strip HTML tags from your string. `information about markup`  <-- this part is **not** clear, information = structured data, you did not say anything about how you want to (re)structure it.