# How to run headless Firefox with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-headless

I am running this code with python, selenium, and firefox but still get 'head' version of firefox:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', log_file=sys.stdout)
binary.add_command_line_options('-headless')
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

I also tried some variations of binary:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Nightly\\firefox.exe', log_file=sys.stdout)
        binary.add_command_line_options("--headless")
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that your Firefox version should be 56+ for this to work. Took me a while to figure out why any of the solution posted did not work on mine. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode

Answer (score 348, accepted):

To invoke Firefox Browser headlessly, you can set the `headless` property through `Options()` class as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

---

There's another way to accomplish headless mode. If you need to disable or enable the headless mode in Firefox, without changing the code, you can set the environment variable `MOZ_HEADLESS` to *whatever* if you want Firefox to run headless, or don't set it at all.

This is very useful when you are using for example continuous integration and you want to run the functional tests in the server but still be able to run the tests in normal mode in your PC.

```
$ MOZ_HEADLESS=1 python manage.py test # testing example in Django with headless Firefox
```

or

```
$ export MOZ_HEADLESS=1   # this way you only have to set it once
$ python manage.py test functional/tests/directory
$ unset MOZ_HEADLESS      # if you want to disable headless mode
```

---

### Steps through YouTube Video

- [Mozilla Firefox in Headless Mode through Selenium 3.5.2 (Java)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk)
- [Login into Gmail Account using Headless Chrome through Selenium Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NkzCe1nD2c)

---

### Outro

[How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: Upgraded Selenium (3.14.1) and PhantomJS is now deprecated, so none of my tests worked. Had to switch to Firefox --headless in a hurry. Thanks for this excellent summary

Comment: MOZ_HEADLESS=1 python manage.py test did the trick! No need for xvfb-run anymore (:

Comment: I'd suggest removing at least the first link to YouTube, it's a 15 minutes video to just say `options.addArguments("--headless");`. People don't need to go through YouTube ads to see that.

Comment: is that same from java code perspectives?

Comment: Hello @undetected-selenium Could you give me some tip for this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75858506/how-can-i-click-confirm-button-in-python-capmonster

Answer (score 78):

The first answer does't work anymore.

This worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Python 3.8.2 / 
selenium.__version__ == '3.141.0'

works great!

Comment: add `from selenium import webdriver` to invoke `webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: The accepted answer still works with the latest version of `Firefox` and `geckodriver`

Comment: @PedroLobito : `options.headless = True` works but throws a deprecation warning: `DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('-headless')`
It's good to avoid these in the long term because they mean it'll stop working eventually.

Comment: THis is also the way to go for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 14):

My answer:

```
set_headless(headless=True) is deprecated.
```

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html

```
options.headless = True
```

works for me

Comment: `options.headless` also has been deprecated  will need `options.add_argument("-headless")`
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

Comment: Despite that site stating Chrome, that change is also needed for Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

You can run headless Firefox with [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) in Python as shown below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("-headless") # Here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Or:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("-headless") # Here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

In addition, the examples below can test Django Admin with headless Firefox, Selenium, [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Django](https://github.com/django/django). *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461862/how-to-run-my-python-selenium-scripts-using-browser/77029091#77029091) explains how to test Django Admin with multiple headless browsers(Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox), Selenium, pytest-django and Django:

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def firefox_driver_init(request):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = firefox_driver
    yield
    firefox_driver.close()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Firefox(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Or:

```py
# "tests/conftest.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def firefox_driver_init(request):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = firefox_driver
    yield
    firefox_driver.close()
```

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Firefox(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Used below code to set driver type based on need of Headless / Head for both Firefox and chrome:

// Can pass browser type 

if brower.lower() == 'chrome':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
elif brower.lower() == 'headless chrome':
    ch_Options = Options()
    ch_Options.add_argument('--headless')
    ch_Options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver',options=ch_Options)
elif brower.lower() == 'firefox':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'..\drivers\geckodriver.exe')
elif brower.lower() == 'headless firefox':
    ff_option = FFOption()
    ff_option.add_argument('--headless')
    ff_option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'..\drivers\geckodriver.exe', options=ff_option)
elif brower.lower() == 'ie':
    driver = webdriver.Ie('..\drivers\IEDriverServer')
else:
    raise Exception('Invalid Browser Type')
```

Answer (score 4):

To the OP or anyone currently interested, here's the section of code that's worked for me with firefox currently:

```
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.add_argument('-headless')
ffox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='\path\to\geckodriver', options=opt)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', firefox_options=options) 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Tested, works as expected and this is from [Official - Headless Mode | Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode#Selenium_in_Python)

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays with this code:

```
options                 = Options()
options.headless        = True
driver                  = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(),options=options)
```

We have a warning:

**DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object**

Changing to this one, works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# selenium drivers: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/
# pip3 install selenium
# pip3 install webdriver-manager
# for custom firefox installation: link firefox to /usr/bin/firefox, example: ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox-bin /usr/bin/firefox

from selenium                           import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox          import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

options                 = Options()
options.headless        = True
service                 = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver                  = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("http://google.com/")
print("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```