# How to use --screenshot in headless firefox in Selenium with python

Tags: selenium, screenshot, headless

Using @DebanjanB's reply in [How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243), 
I'm trying to use his code and change it to use --screenshot argument, but it's not working. 
This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument( "--screenshot test.jpg http://google.com/" )
driver = webdriver.Firefox( firefox_options=options )
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print driver.title
driver.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Can someone let me know please how to use --screenshot with Python and Firefox? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Nevermind, I found a way. there is a function driver.save_screenshot('test.png'). I kept the line from my question and commented it out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import sys

options = Options()
options.add_argument( "--headless" )
# options.add_argument( "--screenshot test.jpg http://google.com/" )
driver = webdriver.Firefox( firefox_options=options )
driver.get('http://google.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
print driver.title
print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
sys.exit()
```