# Selenium grid - node configuration file for Firefox not reading moz:firefoxOptions

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have setup my selenium grid (currently 1 hub and 1 node).
The hub is working fine but for my node I setup the below configuration file (nodeconfig.json)
I wanted to start the firefox in headless mode but it looks like the "moz:firefoxOptions" configuration did not catch up.
I tried setting the "moz:firefoxOptions" in a variety of location in side the json file without any luck :( .

I are using :
windows server 2016 64bit ,
selenium-server-standalone 3.9.1
geckodriver v0.19.1
firefox v59.0

we are running the node using the following command :
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json
I can tell that the configuration file was read as I can see it in the selenium grid console.

nodeconfig.json file:

```
    {
        "capabilities": [
            {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
            "alwaysMatch": {
            "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                "args": [
                    "-headless"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
        ],
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 5,
        "port": 5555,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
        "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
        "nodePolling": 5000,
        "role": "node",
        "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
        "downPollingLimit": 2,
        "debug": false,
        "servlets": [],
        "withoutServlets": [],
        "custom": {}
    }
```

In addition from the logs I can tell that the argument is not added.

The relevant line is :

1520854660258   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.03tQm3hduVDR"**

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the *argument* is **`--headless`** not `-headless`. So possibly you have to change to :

```
"moz:firefoxOptions": {
"args": [
    "--headless"
    ]
}
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but it didn't worked.
also the link you sent me refer to local selenium using firefox webdriver and not selenium grid using remote webdriver.

I have also try the following jsons without any luck:
1.
 "moz:firefoxOptions": {
  "args": [
   "--headless"
   ]
  }
2.
 "alwaysMatch": {
    "moz:firefoxOptions": {
  "args": [
   "--headless"
   ]
  }
      }