# Selenium Python selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused using geckodriver and firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm having issues running my automation test scripts. When I run my script, a browser will appear but it will not type the URL and waits for 10 seconds until it throws an exception. Is there any solutions I can use so then I can get my automation test scripts to work?

**Geckodriver.log**:

```
1523997052492   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1523997052531   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:37807
1523997052592   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.PU1cngaAJ5Tg"
1523997054831   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
```

**Stack Traces**:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"/home/kavin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Testing/purchaseAmazonItems.py", line 13, in setUp
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options=opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

**Code**:

```
def setUp(self):
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/firefox')
    opts = FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options=opts)
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
```

**Specs**:

> Ubuntu 16.04 
> geckodriver 0.20.1 
> firefox
>   59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 
> Python 3.6 
> Pycharm 2016.3 
> Selenium 3.11.0

Comment: Why do you want to do a `driver = self.driver`? Additionally consider updating the question with error stack trace instead of separate `Exceptions` and `Geckodriver.log` sections along with your binary versions.

Comment: @DebanjanB The reason why I did `driver = self.driver` was because I don't want to keep typing `self.driver` every time. Is that best practices? Also I updated my post with error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB my exceptions is pretty similar to my stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In absence of the *error stack trace* configuration issues are pretty hard to debug. Having said that I don't see any major issues in your code block. You may require to perform some additional steps as follows :

- Pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* as follows :

  ```
  def setUp(self):
      binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/firefox')
      opts = FirefoxOptions()
      opts.add_argument("--headless")
      self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options=opts, executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
      driver = self.driver
      driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
  ```
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also try to use the `set_headless(headless=boolean_value)` as follows :

```
def setUp(self):
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/firefox')
    opts = FirefoxOptions()
    opts.set_headless(headless=True)
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options=opts, executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve my issue by adding the following  executable path `executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver`

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB When validating my directories, I saw I have `/usr/bin/firefox` instead of `/usr/bin/firefox/firefox`, so I edited the code like this --> `binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')` and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

These two commands both start a webdriver on the same port. The second one causes the error because the port is already in use:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)
```

To correct this, set the options before initializing the driver (in the first command).

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options=opts)
```

Comment: I tried the following the solutions you provided and it still producing the same issue. I updated my post with my updated code. and gecko logs