# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused while launching Firefox browser through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

It opens firefox but does not get the link and shows this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

### Configuration:

- selenium latest version
- browser latest version
- python 2.7.14
- os:kali linux 2.0

geckodriver log:

```
1527001787163   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1527001787169   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:51383
1527001788204   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.IKjgvyUQaThG"
1527001790297   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
```

[[image: problem]]

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

...implies that [**`WebDriverException`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException) which is the **base webdriver exception** was raised as the driver failed to start its internal server to communicate with the python client.

Though you mentioned about *selenium latest version* and *browser latest version*, the exact details would have helped us to diagnose the issue in a much easier way.

Again, though you mentioned the *message* but I don't see any error in *geckodriver log*.

Try the following steps :

- Pass the *Key* `executable_path` along with the *Value* referring to the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
  browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
  ```
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Presumably, there was an instance of *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Browser Client* active previously, so always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [**`How to fix “WebDriverException: Message: connection refused”?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920639/how-to-fix-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused/47921529#47921529)
- [**`Selenium Python selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused using geckodriver and firefox`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885701/selenium-python-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-connecti/49908110#49908110)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'you web driver full path')
driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/")
```

Comment: this open browser but not entering the link

Comment: how did you define the executable_path ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill all firefox processes to release the resources.

Add this line to kill.sh

```
kill $(ps aux | awk '/firefox/ {print $2}')
```

run

```
sh kill.sh
```