# Connection refused geckodriver with updated firefox version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, apache-superset

I have an application running on a server, that has these packages' versions:

- geckodriver -- 0.24.0
- python -- 3.6.9
- firefox -- 68.5.0esr
- selenium -- 3.141.0

I have updated firefox locally to this version:

- firefox -- 68.7.0esr

I get this error when I try to run the application:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused`

This is the 'geckodriver.log' file result:

```
1587486155678   mozrunner::runner   DEBUG   Killing process 56
1587486155682   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
```

Why is this occurring? According to the [mapping between geckodriver releases, and required versions of Selenium and Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) there shouldn't be any compatability issues.

Full error log:

```
superset-worker_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
superset-worker_1  |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/app/superset/app.py", line 114, in __call__
superset-worker_1  |     return task_base.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 650, in __protected_call__
superset-worker_1  |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/app/superset/tasks/schedules.py", line 373, in schedule_email_report
superset-worker_1  |     deliver_dashboard(schedule)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/app/superset/tasks/schedules.py", line 211, in deliver_dashboard
superset-worker_1  |     driver = create_webdriver()
superset-worker_1  |   File "/app/superset/tasks/schedules.py", line 163, in create_webdriver
superset-worker_1  |     driver = driver_class(**kwargs)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
superset-worker_1  |     keep_alive=True)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
superset-worker_1  |     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
superset-worker_1  |     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
superset-worker_1  |     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
superset-worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
superset-worker_1  |     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
superset-worker_1  | selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Python code:

```
WEBDRIVER_CONFIGURATION: Dict[Any, Any] = {'log_path': '/app/superset/geckodriver.log'}
def create_webdriver():
    driver_class = firefox.webdriver.WebDriver
    options = firefox.options.Options()

    options.log.level = "debug"
    options.add_argument("--headless")

    # Prepare args for the webdriver inits
    kwargs = dict(options=options)
    kwargs.update(WEBDRIVER_CONFIGURATION)

    # Initialize the driver
    driver = driver_class(**kwargs)

    # Some webdrivers need an initial hit to the welcome URL
    # before we set the cookie
    welcome_url = _get_url_path("Superset.welcome")

    # Hit the welcome URL and check if we were asked to login
    driver.get(welcome_url) 
# ... code continues
```

Comment: what is your test env? do you have enough resources? try with lower version of firefox?

Comment: @Infern0 What do you mean by "do I have enough resources"? Sorry if that sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: compute resources: ram/cpu/storage etc...

Comment: @Infern0, yes I do. I am running it on Docker, and i have allocated enough memory there

Comment: Since you are running in docker, can you provide logs from the browser node, or the container that you are using.

Comment: @Infern0 I added the full error log from the container

Comment: can you paste some of the code as init of driver, driver.get .. etc

Comment: i am almost positive this will solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908110/10413416

Comment: @Infern0 I added the code for the webdriver creation

Comment: @Infern0 the linked solution does not work

Comment: I think Celery has a bug with Selenium