# Run Ranorex on Headless Endpoint

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ranorex, selenium-server

I'm trying to set up an automatic web test environment using Ranorex and Selenium Web Driver. As the test will be integrated in Jenkings and run on a machine without graphical interface. I'm trying to set up an endpoint with headless browsers.

I start the selenium-standalone server and gekoDriver with the script:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe" 
selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
```

How do you I manage to set up the Geko and Google Driver in headless mode?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `Ranorex` but in Selenium, for Firefox, you just need to set the `set_headless` options to a boolean true or false to run the browser in headless mode.

For Python, it's like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

Code and documentation and explanation is given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python). Credits to the user Debanjan for this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick answer. I used Selenium in Java before, and I configured it similarly . My problem is that I need to configure this option in ranorex now

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to add an endpoint configuration in Ranorex with the capabilities in JSON:
For example for Firefox:

```
{
"browserName": "firefox",
    "moz:firefoxOptions": {  
         "args" : ['-headless']
     }
}
```

The endpoint will now start the gekoDriver with 'headless' option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the correct JSON capabilities.

For Firefox, the required JSON capabilities are:

```
{
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "moz:firefoxOptions": { 
        "args" : ['-headless']
    }
}
```

For Chrome, you have to use these capabilities:

```
{
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": { 
        "args" : ["headless"]
    }
}
```

The other browser don't support headless (yet), as far as I know.