# Python, PhantomJS says I am not using headless?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='driver/bin/phantomjs.exe')
driver.get("https://www.test.com")
print(driver.current_url)
```

It seems to run fine but before it runs I always get this error:

> UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless

Why am I getting this error? I thought my PhantomJS was headless as it still works and no browser pops-up is this error save to ignore?

Comment: PhantomJS is based on an old version of webkit and is no longer being maintained.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

Comment: Ah ok, @generalhenry is there an easy way to make Chrome or Firefox headless?

Comment: https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/ short version install chrome, chromedriver then in your code call `driver = webdriver.Chrome . . .` and the rest of your code should function as is.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python for firefox

Comment: but still PhontomJS is much faster and needed for Large scale carawling project.

Answer (score 26):

Selenium considers PhantomJS as deprecated, so you need to us either Chrome or Firefox in headless mode.

Here are the steps to use Chrome in headless mode:

1. download chrome driver from  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started
2. extract it to a folder
3. add this folder to your [PATH environment variable](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html) (if you don't do it, you will have to use `webdriver.Chrome('/your/path/to/chromedriver')` in the code below instead of webdriver.Chrome())

Then use it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# prepare the option for the chrome driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

# start chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')
print(browser.current_url)
browser.quit()
```

More on [how to use ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)
For the other options: [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) (also [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py) and [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100025/selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions))

Comment: This method now also seems to be deprecated. I tried it, and it said this:

```DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)```

Comment: @RyanHart, what is your version of ChromeDriver and selenium? I have `ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30` and selenium `3.141.0`(I updated both of them just now). I just checked the code in my answer and I don't have any error. If you still have an error try `browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)` instead of `browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)` and let me know if you still get an error

Comment: I have those exact versions installed as well, but it still gives me that deprecation warning. I did, however, get it to work by removing the `options` lines as well as all parameters in `webdriver.Chrome()`. So, I don't need any more help. Perhaps you have warnings like these suppressed in your settings somehow. I don't know. Everything is good on my end though, now.

Comment: Oh you're right. `options=options` fixed the deprecation warning message. When I tried earlier, I hadn't even scripted anything yet, so all I saw was the warning message an assumed it wouldn't work. I tried tinkering with it again since I decided I wanted to disable all images and javascript to speed up my script.

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium 3.8.1 PhantomJS marked as deprecated webdriver and recommend us to use either Chrome or Firefox in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_path/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://www.test.com")
print(browser.current_url)
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Found an alternative you can add `options.add_argument('headless')` to chrome