# Selenium scrolling and scraping with BeautifulSoup produces duplicate results

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have this script to download images from Instagram. The only issue I am having is that when Selenium starts scrolling down to the bottom of the webpage, BeautifulSoup starts grabbing the same `img src` links after requests is being looped.

Although it will continue to scroll down and download pictures, after all that is done, I end up having 2 or 3 duplicates. So my question is is there a way of preventing this duplication from happening?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver


url = ('https://www.instagram.com/kitties')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

scroll_delay = 0.5
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
counter = 0

print('[+] Downloading:\n')

def screens(get_name):
    with open("/home/cha0zz/Desktop/photos/img_{}.jpg".format(get_name), 'wb') as f:
        r = requests.get(img_url)
        f.write(r.content)

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(scroll_delay)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    imgs = soup.find_all('img', class_='_2di5p')
    for img in imgs:
        img_url = img["src"]
        print('=> [+] img_{}'.format(counter))
        screens(counter)
        counter = counter + 1

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

**Update:**
So I placed this part of the code outside of `while True` and let selenium load the whole page first in order to hopefully have bs4 scrape all the images. It works to number 30 only and then stops.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
imgs = soup.find_all('img', class_='_2di5p')
for img in imgs:
    #tn = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    img_url = img["src"]
    print('=> [+] img_{}'.format(counter))
    screens(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it only loads 30 in your second version of your script is because the rest of the elements are removed from the page DOM and are no longer part of the source that BeautifulSoup sees. The solution is to keep doing what you were doing the first time, but to remove any duplicate elements before you iterate through the list and call `screens()`. You can do this [using sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) as below, though I'm not sure if this is the absolute most efficient way to do it:

```
import requests
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = ('https://www.instagram.com/cats/?hl=en')
driver.get(url)

scroll_delay = 3
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
counter = 0

print('[+] Downloading:\n')

def screens(get_name):
    with open("test_images/img_{}.jpg".format(get_name), 'wb') as f:
        r = requests.get(img_url)
        f.write(r.content)

old_imgs = set()

while True:

    imgs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2di5p')

    imgs_dedupe = set(imgs) - set(old_imgs)

    for img in imgs_dedupe:
        img_url = img.get_attribute("src")
        print('=> [+] img_{}'.format(counter))
        screens(counter)
        counter = counter + 1

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(scroll_delay)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    old_imgs = imgs

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

driver.quit()
```

As you can see, I used a different page to test it, one with 420 images of cats. The result was 420 images, the number of posts on that account, with no duplicates among them.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Exactly what I needed to do. Thanks a lot for that. Is there any good read or some samples for this you showed me? You said using `sets()` ?

Comment: If you want information on sets you can look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset) for sets, and in particular for the [`difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference) method, which lets you remove duplicates in A that also appear in B by doing A - B. I came up with this answer by looking through a bunch of sources, but I didn't find anything good enough to recommend on this.

Comment: Ok, No problem. I also see that you changed from soup to `imgs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2di5p')` So basically soup doesn't have to be used at all?

Comment: Yes, I got rid of `BeautifulSoup` because it's not necessary, as Selenium can parse the elements just as well. No point having an extra dependency if you can avoid it. I wonder if you can go without using `requests` as well, but it seems to work just fine as it is so I see no reason to change it.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly as is. I am just gonna clean up the code a little, and figure out to run webdriver silently, so it doesn't open the browser every time

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768243/9374673) on running the Firefox browser in headless mode.

Comment: Awesome. Now it runs silently :) Thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

I would use os library to check if file already exists

```
import os


def screens(get_name):
    with open("/home/cha0zz/Desktop/photos/img_{}.jpg".format(get_name), 'wb') as f:
        if os.path.isfile(path/to/the/file):      #checks file exists. Gives false on directory
    # or if os.path.exists(path/to/the/file): #checks file/directory exists
            pass
        else:
            r = requests.get(img_url)
            f.write(r.content)
```

*I might have messed up the ordering of if and with statements

Comment: The issue is that it's fetching the same url while selenium is loading the page.

Comment: hm....so? You said you're having file duplicates. My solution if to check if files exists before saving it in order to avoid duplicates. Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

Comment: Also, regarding your update. I think it loads up to 30 because DOM loads that far. You might wanna try to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page, and only then soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml'). @uzdisral

Comment: selenium loads the full page, but the soup won't download all of it. It goes to 30 max and stops