# How do i get selenium webdriver to stop opening browser?

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

I'm trying to scrape a website to get the pictures and all I'm interested in is their links.  Which I have to wait till the website javascript loads.  I'm able to get the information I need, but I don't need firefox to open every time I run my code.  Is there a way to just load my html code without the browser opening everytime?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/iotd.html")

print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @s.bridges will work, but `set_headless()` has been deprecated.  So you should use the `headless` property instead.  Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/iotd.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean run it headless? This will allow Firefox to be used but not visibly.

I went to pull up the docs and saw this was a pretty solid post on setting up headless Firefox.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/iotd.html")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Hope this answers your question!

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768243/9546468)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20799728)

Comment: @Salman Thank you. I didn't give it much thought to that. Will do from now on!