# DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True) using Geckodriver and Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, webdriverwait

I have a very basic Python script that runs perfectly on my local machine (Mint 19), and yet fails on a remote box (Ubuntu 16.04). Same files, both Python 3.7. I have geckodriver in /usr/local/bin and it checks out from path with gecko --version from the command line. I can't figure out what the problem is. The geckodriver.log file just says:

```
1541268536111   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.Mt6zAyZc7D01"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1541268546125   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 33632
```

The error from the terminal is:

```
root@dev1:/home/krypterro/PycharmProjects/corbot# python3 test1.py
 2018-11-03 12:28:22,442 -  INFO -  Application - Start
test1.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless
  opts.set_headless(headless=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 14, in main
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: timed out
```

Here is the Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    logging.info('Application - Start')
    # Operate in headless mode
    opts = Options()
    opts.set_headless(headless=True)
    assert opts.headless
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    driver.get("https://www.krypterro.com")
    html_src = driver.page_source
    print(html_src)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    logging.info('Application - End')
main()
```

I have port 4444 allowed in the firewall on the remote box, but as it's a local-to-local connection I am not sure that should even matter.

Comment: that deprecation warning is not related to the WebDriverException after it..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This information log...

```
INFO - Application - Start test1.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True)
```

...implies that the **`set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True)`** is **deprecated** and you have to use the **setter** for headless property as follows:

```
opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
driver.get("https://www.krypterro.com")
```

You can find the detailed discussion in [How to make firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python)

Moving ahead as you are trying to retrive the *Page Source* and as the [Web Application](https://www.krypterro.com/) is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.krypterro.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(.,'Products and Services')]")))
    html_src = driver.page_source
    print(html_src)
    driver.quit()
```

**Note B**: You don't need to invoke `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` rather always invoke `driver.quit()` only within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: while it's a good idea to avoid deprecated code, the deprecation warning is just a warning printer to stderr.  The OP's stacktrace shows an actual error occurring after that..

Comment: Added that fix for the headless, the warning goes away, thanks for that. But I still get the same error, and it still crashes.

Comment: @krypterro Checkout my updated Answer and let me know the status

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to some weird network issues on the specific VPS server, I spun up a new box, and the code above works, and now doesn't throw the error. Thank you.