# Handling headless mode in different browsers using Selenium Python client

Tags: python, selenium, headless, google-chrome-headless, firefox-headless

I am currently working on a python (3.7) CLI program that uses Selenium and will be used by a diverse group of people.

The problem I ran into was the following:

For setting options like "headless" in **Chrome** I use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path,options=chrome_options)
```

For **Firefox**, the code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path,options=options)
```

So I wanted to know if there is a way to normalise these settings/ handle different browsers  elegantly or do I have to write everything basically 2 or even 3 (might add Safari or Opera) times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the *Change Log* of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) *Python* client *v3.12.0*:

> - Deprecate Options `set_headless` methods in favor of property setter

Hence, if you are using Selenium [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) v *3.12.0* or above, instead of `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` you need to use the **`headless`** property setter as follows:

```
options.headless = True
```

Else you may see a `DeprecationWarning` as follows:

```
DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True)
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True) using Geckodriver and Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134306/deprecationwarning-use-setter-for-headless-property-instead-of-set-headless-opt/53135400#53135400)

---

### References

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [How to make firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)
- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)