# Not start Chromium with headless mode from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium, headless

Lately one of my python selenium script running on Raspi4 linux stops working properly. The same code worked well before and I'm trying to figure out the reason.

The example code below works without headless option, but it is stuck in starting Chromium. Does anyone encounter similar issue?
Chromium and chromedriver version is 97.0.4692.99.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

url = 'https://www.google.com'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')
#options.add_argument('-headless')
#options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.headless = True

service = ChromeService(executable_path='C:\selenium\driver\chromedriver.exe')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

chrome.get(url)

chrome.save_screenshot('xx.png')
chrome.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `--headless` argument, you need to use the **`headless`** property as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless opts.set_headless(headless=True) using Geckodriver and Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134306/deprecationwarning-use-setter-for-headless-property-instead-of-set-headless-opt/53135400#53135400)
- [How to make Firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)
- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: why this way is better than the OP option?