# How to accelerate this process of JavaScript web-page scraping?

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping

This python function aims to scrape a specific identifier (called as PMID) from a JavaScript web-page. When a URL is passed to the function, it gets the page using selenium. The code then tries to find the class "pubmedLink" within  tag of html. If found, it returns the extracted PMID to another function.

This works fine, but is literally really slow. Is there a way to accelerate the process may be by using another parser or with a completely different method?

```
from selenium import webdriver


def _getPMIDfromURL_(url):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/protoLivingSystematicReviews/drivers/chromedriver')
    driver.get(url)

    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.pubmedLink').is_displayed():
            json_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.pubmedLink').text
            return json_text
    except:
        return "no_pmid"

    driver.quit()
```

Examples of the URL for the JS web-page,

- http://www.embase.com/search/results?subaction=viewrecord&from=export&id=L617434973
- http://www.embase.com/search/results?subaction=viewrecord&from=export&id=L617388849
- http://www.embase.com/search/results?subaction=viewrecord&from=export&id=L46141767

Comment: Do you have to have a login to view this pages?

Comment: @QHarr I think it must be accessible only through the universities in EFTA region. Dang! Others cannot access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, selenium is fast, that's why is the favorite for many testers. On the other hand you could improve your code by parsing the content once instead two times.

The return value of the  statement

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.pubmedLink')
```

might by stored in a variable and use that variable. This will improve your speed about 1.5x.

```
try:
    elem =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.pubmedLink')
    if  elem.is_displayed():
        return elem.text
except:
    return "no_pmid
```

Comment: Where do I parse the URL without the statement driver.get(url) ?

Comment: I get what you mean now, but this statement (if  elem.is_displayed():) does't work. I tried it without the statement and it functions a bit better, but is there a way to just parse this ID and not the entire url? Any hints welcome.

Comment: No, the is no way you can parse just that ID, all the text (at least until that ID is reached) has to be parsed, that's the way it can later get elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try phantomjs, its faster:
https://realpython.com/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/

Comment: "Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead"

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python options.headless = True

Comment: Yes, I tried it too. the speed seems to be the same or worse.