# can't select specific html element using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find an element that's a tbody nested inside the all_totals id (it's definitely there, I checked).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html'
data = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

print(html.select('#all_totals tbody').prettify())
```

However, this beautiful soup code just returns an empty array. I thought the problem might somehow be caused by the desired element sitting under a GIANT html comment. I added some code to attempt to parse the html to get rid of the comment:

```
for comment in html.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    comment.extract()
print(html.select('#all_totals')[0].prettify())
```

This worked in getting rid of the comment; however, most (but not all) of the html nested within the 'all_totals' id disappeared after doing this.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correctly select the html that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selenium` to find directly the `tbody`, because it is loaded by javascript.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

print(html.find('div', {'id':'all_totals'}).find('tbody').prettify())

for comment in html.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    comment.extract()
print(html.find('div', {'id': 'all_totals'}).prettify())
```

Comment: thanks so much, this worked! whenever I run this code, it opens up the firefox link, is there anyway around that?

Comment: found a solution to stop firefox opening up a window for anyone curious: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768243/8780895

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `extract` as you will remove the comments which contain the html of interest. See the following as an example of extracting from comment instead

```
import pandas as pd

for comment in html.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if 'id="totals"' in comment:
        table = pd.read_html(comment)[0]
        print(table)
        break
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the html I wanted is below a comment, not inside a comment, sorry if that was poorly explained in my post