# Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities error using Selenium and GeckoDriver while loading on live server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I have to build an web application on a linux webserver that will use selenium with firefox . When I run the application the the linux server "localhost:5000" it works perfectly fine . But when i tried it with "127.0.0.1:80" it is not giving me an error during webdriver loading:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

Error:

```
"Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"
```

In nginx access.log it is producing a http 200 and there is nothing on error.log
in geckodriver.log it produce:

```
Listening on port 41209
```

Environment details:

- selenium = 3.8.0
- geckodriver = 0.18.0
- Firefox version 53
- python = 3.6

nginx imageApp.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 127.0.0.1;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/administator/imageDetectionApplication/imageDetectionApplication.sock;
    }
}
```

[imageDetectionApplication.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieKPS.png)

I am completely new in linux server...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.8.0* which is almost **2.5 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is *unknown* to us.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is *0.18.0* which is older.
- Your *Firefox* version is *53* which is also pretty old.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.8.0* , *GeckoDriver v0.18.0* and the *Firefox Browser v53*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current *Firefox v72.0* levels.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “Unable to find a matching set of capabilities” despite driver being in /usr/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953524/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in/53953692#53953692)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with Firefox 46 through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/47785513#47785513)
- [Selenium WebDriver, Firefox, Centos, unable to find a matching set of capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577576/selenium-webdriver-firefox-centos-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabiliti/57581533#57581533)
- [Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with selenium 3.4.3, firefox 54.0 and gecko driver 0.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601126/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-4-3-firefox-54-0/44601664#44601664)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002958/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/52006033#52006033)

Comment: thanks for your reply . Unfortunately I am out of office till sunday . I will revert to the updated system on monday and let you know the result.

Comment: DebanjanB .....  I have updated the latest     1)selenium->3.141   2) Firefox->72  and 3)geckodriver->0.26.0.......  then I put the geckodriver on /usr/local/bin and made it executable...............   now the error is 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: @raymax Great. So the current issue is solved. _'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH_ seems to be a new error. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?