# Errors in using Selenium Webdriver in Skill Lab of IBM (online Jupyter notebook) with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, jupyter-notebook, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried different ways to make work Selenium in my Python script to scraping web with an [online Jupyter notebook](https://labs.cognitiveclass.ai/tools/jupyterlab/) without any success. I read many other instructions (like [this](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/), [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-with-selenium-d7b6d8d3265a)) or answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713445/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913202/message-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-error-using-selenium-and) and many others) about similar questions but nothing seems work for me.
On the virtual environment I downloaded both Firefox (v81.0) and geckodriver (v0.27) in the development folder, and I gave both all the permissions:

```
jupyterlab@jupyterlab-sps:/resources/testDevelop$ ls -l
total 7797

drwxrwsr-x 8 jupyterlab resources    4096 Oct  8 13:24 firefox
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jupyterlab resources 7274984 Oct  8 13:21 geckodriver
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources     120 Oct 12 08:47 geckodriver.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources   31813 Oct 12 09:42 testDevelop.ipynb
```

and

```
jupyterlab@jupyterlab-sps:/resources/testDevelop/firefox$ ls -l
total 165651
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       825 Sep 30 14:26 Throbber-small.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       895 Sep 30 15:49 application.ini
drwxrwsr-x 4 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 browser
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    241720 Sep 30 16:28 crashreporter
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      4003 Sep 30 14:26 crashreporter.ini
drwxrwsr-x 3 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 defaults
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       174 Sep 30 16:28 dependentlibs.list
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     14656 Sep 30 16:28 firefox
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    569104 Sep 30 16:28 firefox-bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      1449 Sep 30 16:32 firefox-bin.sig
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      1449 Sep 30 16:32 firefox.sig
drwxrwsr-x 2 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 fonts
drwxrwsr-x 3 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 gmp-clearkey
drwxrwsr-x 2 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 gtk2
drwxrwsr-x 2 jupyterlab resources      4096 Oct  8 13:24 icons
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    895568 Sep 30 16:28 libfreeblpriv3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    691064 Sep 30 16:28 libgraphitewasm.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     43408 Sep 30 16:28 liblgpllibs.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources   2175768 Sep 30 16:28 libmozavcodec.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    220128 Sep 30 16:28 libmozavutil.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     14352 Sep 30 16:28 libmozgtk.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    113512 Sep 30 16:28 libmozsandbox.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources   1207424 Sep 30 16:28 libmozsqlite3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     18376 Sep 30 16:28 libmozwayland.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    243728 Sep 30 16:28 libnspr4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    694896 Sep 30 16:28 libnss3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    465616 Sep 30 16:28 libnssckbi.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    191728 Sep 30 16:28 libnssutil3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    184120 Sep 30 16:28 liboggwasm.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     22872 Sep 30 16:28 libplc4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources     14592 Sep 30 16:28 libplds4.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    168024 Sep 30 16:28 libsmime3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    326208 Sep 30 16:28 libsoftokn3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    406208 Sep 30 16:28 libssl3.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources 131841712 Sep 30 16:28 libxul.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      1449 Sep 30 16:32 libxul.so.sig
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources   1260688 Sep 30 16:28 minidump-analyzer
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources  26270759 Sep 30 16:32 omni.ja
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    614144 Sep 30 16:28 pingsender
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       166 Sep 30 16:28 platform.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    564936 Sep 30 16:28 plugin-container
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      1449 Sep 30 16:32 plugin-container.sig
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources      2017 Sep 30 16:32 precomplete
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources         0 Sep 30 16:28 removed-files
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       132 Sep 30 16:28 update-settings.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jupyterlab resources    101864 Sep 30 16:28 updater
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jupyterlab resources       638 Sep 30 16:28 updater.ini
```

I also added the path of firefox and geckodriver to the env variable paths, that is:

```
jupyterlab@jupyterlab-sps:/resources/testDevelop/firefox$ echo $PATH
/resources/testDevelop:/resources/testDevelop/firefox:/resources/firefox:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/jupyterlab/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/jre1.8.0_211/bin:/home/jupyterlab/hadoop-2.9.2/bin:/home/jupyterlab/spark-2.4.3/bin
```

But if I try this code:

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver=Firefox(executable_path='/resources/testDevelop/geckodriver',)
```

I got this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e332a8e620e3> in <module>
      6 from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
      7 
----> 8 driver=Firefox(executable_path='/resources/testDevelop/geckodriver',)
      9 cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
     10 cap["marionette"] = False

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    177         else:
    178             if self.binary is None:
--> 179                 self.binary = FirefoxBinary()
    180             if self.profile is None:
    181                 self.profile = FirefoxProfile()

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in __init__(self, firefox_path, log_file)
     45         self.command_line = None
     46         if self._start_cmd is None:
---> 47             self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
     48         if not self._start_cmd.strip():
     49             raise WebDriverException(

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in _get_firefox_start_cmd(self)
    167                 raise RuntimeError(
    168                     "Could not find firefox in your system PATH." +
--> 169                     " Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
    170         return start_cmd
    171 

RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

so I tried:

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
driver = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geckodriver'))
binary = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'firefox', 'firefox'))
ff_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=binary, log_file='ff_log.log')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=driver)
```

But I got this strange error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-0bb63b20498c> in <module>
     12 binary = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'firefox', 'firefox'))
     13 ff_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=binary, log_file='ff_log.log')
---> 14 browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=driver)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    189 
    190             executor = ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile,
--> 191                                            self.binary, timeout)
    192             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
    193                 self,

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py in __init__(self, host, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout)
     50         self.profile.add_extension()
     51 
---> 52         self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
     53         _URL = "http://%s:%d/hub" % (HOST, PORT)
     54         RemoteConnection.__init__(

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in launch_browser(self, profile, timeout)
     70         self.profile = profile
     71 
---> 72         self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
     73         self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
     74 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in _start_from_profile_path(self, path)
     93         self.process = Popen(
     94             command, stdout=self._log_file, stderr=STDOUT,
---> 95             env=self._firefox_env)
     96 
     97     def _wait_until_connectable(self, timeout=30):

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    685         (p2cread, p2cwrite,
    686          c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 687          errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
    688 
    689         # We wrap OS handles *before* launching the child, otherwise a

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _get_handles(self, stdin, stdout, stderr)
   1202             else:
   1203                 # Assuming file-like object
-> 1204                 c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
   1205 
   1206             if stderr is None:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I've not understood what's the problem with this error. I've checked singularly the values of addresses and they seems correct, that is:

- binary returns: '/resources/StockScreener/firefox/firefox'
- driver returns: '/resources/StockScreener/geckodriver'
- ff_binary returns: <selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary at 0x7f10b681e160>

I also tried to use GeckoDriverManager in this way:

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
driver = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geckodriver'))
binary = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'firefox', 'firefox'))
ff_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=binary, log_file='ff_log.log')
#browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=driver)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

and returns:

```
[WDM] - Driver [/home/jupyterlab/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.27.0/geckodriver] found in cache

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-012cab2ea574> in <module>
     13 ff_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=binary, log_file='ff_log.log')
     14 #browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=driver)
---> 15 driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
     16 #browser.get('http://google.com/')
     17 #Simple assignment

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    177         else:
    178             if self.binary is None:
--> 179                 self.binary = FirefoxBinary()
    180             if self.profile is None:
    181                 self.profile = FirefoxProfile()

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in __init__(self, firefox_path, log_file)
     45         self.command_line = None
     46         if self._start_cmd is None:
---> 47             self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
     48         if not self._start_cmd.strip():
     49             raise WebDriverException(

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py in _get_firefox_start_cmd(self)
    167                 raise RuntimeError(
    168                     "Could not find firefox in your system PATH." +
--> 169                     " Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
    170         return start_cmd
    171 

RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

Consider that in all cases, I have:

```
jupyterlab@jupyterlab-sps:/resources/testDevelop/firefox$ whereis firefox
firefox: /resources/testDevelop/firefox /resources/testDevelop/firefox/firefox.sig /resources/testDevelop/firefox/firefox
```

Finally, if I write only:

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
#from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver=Firefox(executable_path='/resources/testDevelop/geckodriver')
```

I got the following error, after restarting the kernel without installing webdriver-manager:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-89dbd2507c70> in <module>
      6 #from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
      7 
----> 8 driver=Firefox(executable_path='/resources/testDevelop/geckodriver')
      9 #cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
     10 #cap["marionette"] = False

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    172                 command_executor=executor,
    173                 desired_capabilities=capabilities,
--> 174                 keep_alive=True)
    175 
    176         # Selenium remote

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

it seems the issue is subject to many updates of versions so new updates can cause mismathes and problems. How to solve? Can you suggest a similar way to make easily web scraping (running JavaScript) maybe using other libs?