# Scraping With Selenium, PhantomJS & BS4

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm currently using Windows 10 and Python 3.7 and I've been reading about how to scrape without opening up 1 Firefox browser window for each URLs that's being scraped in the `urls` list. The code below is throwing an error back and I'm sure it's got something to do with how PhantomJS is being implemented, I just don't know what specifically.

I've read that PhantomJS was a solution when used with Selenium. I installed PJS, set up the Path on my computer and it appears to be running however I'm not completely sure how to implement it in the code itself.

The `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"C:\phantomjs")` line is the line attempting to run the PJS. The code worked just fine before using `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` .

```
urls = ["https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=0&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=90&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=180&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=270&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=360&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=450&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=540&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=630&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=720&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=810&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=900&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=990&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD"]
#url = "https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=180&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD"

user_agent = UserAgent()

#make csv file
csv_file = open("gcscrape.csv", "w", newline='') #added the newline thing on 5.17.20 to try to stop blank lines from writing
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["bass_name","bass_price"])

for url in urls:
    web_r = requests.get(url)
    web_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_r.text,"html.parser")

        #print(web_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container")) #finding all of the grid items on the url above - price, photo, image, details and all
        #print(len(web_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container"))) #printing out the length of the

    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"C:\phantomjs")
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") #whats inside of this is a javascript call to get the outer html content of the page
    sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    for content in sel_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container"):
            #print(content)

        bass_name = content.find("div", class_="productTitle").text.strip() #pulls the bass guitar name
        print(bass_name)

        prices_new = []
        for i in content.find("span", class_="productPrice").text.split("$"):
            prices_new.append(i.strip())
        bp = prices_new[1]
        print(bp)

        #write row to new csv file
        csv_writer.writerow([bass_name, bp])
```

Comment: Hello, are there any requirement for using PhantomJS? I'm asking because it is now deprecated. More information here. https://phantomjs.org/. Firefox has a headless mode and chrome too. As you told it worked with Firefox, here is some instructions on how to run headless mode in firefox. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: Not that I could see, no. All the tutorials that I found were simply go to PhantomJS's website, download the version for Windows, set up a Path for PJS on your computer under My PC > Advanced System Settings and you should be all set. Is the ability to run Firefox headless something that's always been around? Or something that was included by Selenium once PJS depreciated?

Comment: I'm not sure, but since Chrome and Firefox released headless mode, the PhantomJS project started become obsolete, and developers just stopped using it to use Chrome or Firefox headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download the correct PhantomJs distribution for your operational system [here](https://phantomjs.org/download.html).

For Windows, the following line of code should work just fine:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C://phantomjs.exe")
driver.get(url)
```