# Pycharm evaluate expression and actual execution are different

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, firefox-headless

I am using the code from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243) to try and get the HTML of a website, using a headless browser.
Here is my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("-headless")
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--headless")

options.headless = True
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Aviv\\Downloads\\geckodriverv0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe")#,capabilities=cap)
driver.get("https://coronaupdates.health.gov.il/corona-updates/grid/public-transport")
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mat-row"))
```

When I just let the code run and print, the result is an empty list: []
But if I use Pycharm evaluator I get a list with 20 elements.

[image]

It looks like the evaluator and the actual command in the code executed differently, or the assignment did not go well.

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it prints `[]` since the required class elements aren't loaded in the `DOM` and when you use the evaluator it may wait until the full `DOM` update is complete. This is how in the latter case it returns the elements that match the given class.

Try adding a sleep call in your script

```
import time

options.headless = True
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Aviv\\Downloads\\geckodriverv0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe")#,capabilities=cap)
driver.get("https://coronaupdates.health.gov.il/corona-updates/grid/public-transport")

time.sleep(5)   # Delays for 5 seconds.
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mat-row"))
```

Also do evaluate with [Explicit vs Implicit wait calls](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in headless and non-headless mode.