# How to let webdriver.Firefox() open minimized?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But how can I let the browser open up minimized or hidden?

Comment: try launch it headless by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python) stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thank! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

The `headless` property will do the task for you. Import `Options()` from `selenium.webdriver.firefox.options`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

my_opt = Options()
my_opt.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=my_opt, executable_path=r'path_to_your_geckodriver')
driver.get("url_you_want_to_access")
```

All set!

Comment: Thanks, But somebody already told me that in the comments.  : (

Comment: Glad you found it already!!! you can mark the answer as the correct answer so people know not to try and answer again and people can find it :) Which you can do with the big tick underneath the voting on an answer.