# Webdriver: Undefined name 'driver'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm writing a python script that uses Firefox webdriver. However, the browser instance should not be created until a condition is met.

When testing if browser is already opened, there is a message in Spyder's editor: undefined name 'driver'.

How to change the code to get rid of that message?

```
while True
    if time_to_work():
        if driver.service.is_connectable():            
            do_something()
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options)
            print('Browser started..')
    else:
        if driver.service.is_connectable():
            print('Closing browser..')        
            driver.quit()
```

Comment: What condition are you testing for with `is_connectable`?

Comment: @Mike67 I want to find out if the browser instance needs to be created. Or of it is already there, ready to fetch a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to test `driver.service.is_connectable()` if there's no `driver` instance, so you'll need to have the driver instance declared before the `while True`. You can have the `driver` instance initialized without the actual browser window showing up by using

```
options = Options()
options.headless() = True
```

and initializing the driver using

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'[YOUR GECKODRIVER PATH]')
```

(thanks to the accepted answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python)).
Then you can check `time_to_work()` along with the other conditions.

Comment: This is what I did before, but there is very little memory on my VPS. I'm looking for a way to have an instance only when the "time_to_work" condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

To open the browser on the first pass (lazy loading), initialize the `driver` to `None` then check the value in `time_to_work`

Try this code:

```
driver = None
while True
    if time_to_work():
        if not driver: # start browser
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options)
            print('Browser started..')
        do_something()
    else:
        if driver:
            print('Closing browser..')        
            driver.quit() 
            driver = None
```

Comment: That works fine the first run. But during the second time in the loop occurs an exception: ConnectionRefusedError ErrNo(111) Full log at: https://justpaste.it/1qn1l

Comment: Here is the small testscript I ran to test the idea with driver = None. https://justpaste.it/2r61a

Comment: Answer updated to reset the driver to None. You should change your logic so you only need to open\close the browser once.