# Python PhantomJS using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, selenium4, selenium-webdriver-python

Hello I want try load website with PhantomJS

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Users/martinzuffa/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta-macos/bin/phantomjs")
driver.get("www.google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Here is the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/martinzuffa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 8, in
>
> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Users/martinzuffa/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta-macos/bin/phantomjs")
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py",
> line 52, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 96, in start
> self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 107, in assert_process_still_running
> raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
> /Users/martinzuffa/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta-macos/bin/phantomjs
> unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS was deprecated in [*Selenium 3.8.1*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6ba18695667ebf39611cf63e5a23c2736eef5963/py/CHANGES#L358)

> * PhantomJS is now deprecated, please use either Chrome or Firefox in headless mode

Additionally, [*Selenium 4.1.0*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6ba18695667ebf39611cf63e5a23c2736eef5963/py/CHANGES#L1) packages doesn't contain the ***PhantomJS*** module anymore:

[image: PythonModules]

---

### Solution

As an alternative you have to use either of the following:

- [Firefox in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)
- [Chrome in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: Hi, Can Firefox or Chrome use authenticated proxy in selenium headless mode?