# Where to find all available preferences for selenium for FireFox/Chrome and how to implement them with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to build a TinderBot.

Both Chrome and FireFox ask for geo permission outside of code (the pop-up drops from the browser's address bar, so it's not inside the html and I cannot access it with .find_element)

I found some prompts on Chrome here: https://testingbot.com/support/selenium/permission-popups (didn't try it though, so not sure if they are up to date)

But I cannot find anything for FireFox.

I found this piece of code that disables javascipt
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/firefox/
And I believe that I could build on it, but I cannot find how to set it so that it gives permission for geolocation.

Recently I though I found here a piece that at least might show me how to correctly pass '-hedless' argument but it won't open browser now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('-headless')
srvc = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, service=srvc)
```

So generally I have 2 problems here:

1. How do I make add_argument work? (I mean other cases turned out deprecated)
2. What arguments do I need to target to allow geolocation on launching browser with the bot?

Am I even on the right path? I cannot ask questions in relevant threads because of insufficient rating, so here I am.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate *Firefox* browser in ***headless*** mode instead of using *`add_argument()`* you need to set the ***`headless`*** property to *`true`* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
srvc = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, service=srvc)
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to make Firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768243/7429447)

Comment: I tried just the same lines but it does the same thing: not opening the browser. Though I see how it's trying: the icon in the dock bar tweaks and stops.

Comment: @RZenBridges Of coase you are using **headless** mode and that's enough to observe things working alright. Do remember to invoke `get(url)` later in your code?

Comment: sure, it's there

Comment: I don't see any issue any more. Did you try to print something to confirm if everying is as per your expectation?