# Selenium - Element is not clickable at point because another element obscures it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using following code to download the excel from this web site, the code was working fine but recently the web page may change so my code doesn't work. It returns this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (1250,464) because another element  obscures it

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

geckodriver = '/opt/geckodriver'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ete'))).click()
time.sleep(2)

html = driver.page_source

print(html)
```

I searched the posts in stackoverflow, I found that I can use ActionChains but I dunno how to apply to until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ete')))

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Comment: I would recommend removing the add-headless argument so that you can check what is obstructing your click. It might be a sign in page, cookie page, or even just that the website needs to be scrolled before clicking. Depending on that, you would have different solutions. If it is a sign in or cookie page, you would have to enter credentials or press accept respectively. If the problem is that you need to scroll, you would have to do something like element = some WebElement
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the *Cookie Concent Banner* obscures the click.

---

### Solution

Click on <kbd>Accept</kbd>  button first adding the argument [`--headless=new`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367068/7429447) and you can download the excel inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--headless=new')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ete"))).click()
  ```