# selenium python code is dying after start

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
Option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
Option.add_argument('disable-infobars')
#Option.add_argument('--headless')
Option.add_argument('--log-level=3')
Option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
Option.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')
Option.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
Option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
Option.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
Option.add_argument('--proxy-bypass-list=*')
Option.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
Option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
Option.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{user}\\FreeUse\\CASHER\\Profiles')
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=Option)
driver.get('https://casher2.win/games/wheel')
driver.maximize_window()
```

(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

How do I fix it and what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following *arguments* added through the instance of `ChromeOptions()` unless mandatory:

- *`disable-infobars`*
- *`--log-level=3`*
- *`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`*
- *`ignore-certificate-errors`*
- *`--no-sandbox`*
- *`--proxy-server='direct://'`*
- *`--proxy-bypass-list=*`*
- *`--disable-dev-tools`*
- *`excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']`*

Additionally, you can replace `--headless` with `--headless=new` as [headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75417151/7429447)

Finally, incase you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use [ChromeDriverManager().install()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) anymore as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447)

---

### Solution

Your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
Option.add_argument("--headless=new")
Option.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')
Option.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{user}\\FreeUse\\CASHER\\Profiles')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Option)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```