# Click on HTML elements with Scrapy (WebScraping)

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapysharp

I'm doing a program in c # using scrapySharp or HtmlAgilityPack. But I have the disadvantage of that part of the information that I need, to appear when I click on an HTML element  (Button, link ).

In some forums it was commented that when using Selenium you could manipulate the html elements, so I tried the following

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

    // Defines the interface with the Chrome browser
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
    // Auxiliary to store the label element in href
    Element IWebElement;
    // Go to the website
    driver.Url = url;

    // Click on the download button
    driver.FindElement (By.Id ("Download button")). Click ();
```

but being a web automation test, it opens a browser and the website to perform the selection process (clicks), so it is not of my use, since I have to perform the inspection on several websites internally.

Although I can continue using Selenium, I am looking for ways to avoid using the browser and instead click without it.
Does anyone know how to achieve the click of the link or button, without the need to open a browser for web scraping?

Comment: You can use a headless browser instead, like `PhantomJS` driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would be helpful to anyone who has the same requirements.
If you want to avoid opening the browser, you could use below settings in the ChromeDriver.

```
// settings for avoid opening browser
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

// url to access and scrape
var url = "https://example.com";

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options))
{
    // access the url
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    // Click on the download button - copied from your code above
    driver.FindElement (By.Id ("Download button")). Click (); 
}
```

In addition to above below links also, you may find useful,

[can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background)

[running-webdriver-without-opening-actual-browser-window](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/running-webdriver-without-opening-actual-browser-window)