# Python+Selenium: Is it possible to lock the browser from manual clicks and inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a python selenium code which automates actions on a website. Once user authenticates the log in, selenium takes over the browser and does its thing. Everything works perfectly fine, however, I notice that the code may fail if user accidentally clicks anything on any links while selenium is running.

Is there a way to prevent manual inputs from the user? something like:

```
br = webdriver.chrome()
br.lock_manual_userinput()
```

Comment: Not sure if its an option, but you can [hide the browser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43543955/9348376).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing. You can dedicate machine/s with limited access for running the automation or just be carful if you are working while running the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

*Selenium* is purely used for *automating* of repeatative *Manual Tasks*. At this point it is worth to mention that **Selenium** mocks **User Interactions**.

Hence the statement *once user authenticates the log in, selenium takes over the browser* is pretty much speculative as attempting to [Reconnect Selenium to previous Browsing Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium/47862867#47862867) is not viable.

Now the statement, *"code may fail if user accidentally clicks anything"* is pretty much expected as *Selenium* needs browser **focus**. As a result of any  manual user interaction *Selenium* will loose *focus* and raise an error.

Finally, *there is no other way to prevent manual inputs* as mentioned earlier that *Selenium mocks User Interactions*. The best possible way to execute your *Selenium* based *Automated Tests* preventing manual inputs from the user would be to :

- Set up a *Test Bed* with all the required *Hardware* and *Software* configuration.
- Create the *Test Bed* in an isolated environment preferably in a *Test Lab* free from *Manual Intervention*.
- *Automate* only the required *usecases* which needs no manual intervention.