# How to get access to a page's "Inspect Element" code without opening a new page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use python to get access to the inspect element code from a page that i have already open.

I tried using selenium

```
import selenium

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("mywebsite")
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")
```

It works, giving me the code, but it opens the a new chrome page.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background

Comment: Any reason you are not using BeautifulSoup for what seems to be a web scraping problem?

Comment: @PaulaThomas I am not familiar with BeautifulSoup