# Why does selenium's move_by_offset function sometime waits before executing (Python/Chrome)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium in Chrome with Python to automate some testing and part of that is moving the mouse, as I am creating a lot of test I run them in parallel on threads. The only piece of code that really gives me problems are the following:

```
action =  selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(x,y)
action.perform()
```

For some reason sometime the above will take at least 5 seconds, e.g. 5.03123 seconds, to execute. When there is a delay it is always only slightly above 5, but never below 5, which leads me to believe that somewhere there is a time.sleep(5). I have checked the selenium actionchains file and commented out:

```
self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()
```

in case this was the culprit, but there has been no significant change.

An important note is that this seems to be a larger problem/occurring more often when my window is minimized and I have multiple threads running.

I am very much at a loss on why this happens, and have tried a bunch of different things/test, but basically to no avail. Any and all help is much appreciated.

If you need any additional information or I should run other specific tests let me know and I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong commenting out the line:

```
self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()
```

In `move_by_offset()` method the call to **`key_action.pause()`** is implemented for a purpose which is *Out Of Scope* for this question. By all possible means you souldn't change the *source client code*.

### window is minimized

While executing *Selenium Tests* you need to keep your windows *maximized*.

You will find a related discussion in [Way to open Selenium browser not ovelapping my current browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162992/way-to-open-selenium-browser-not-ovelapping-my-current-browser)

Comment: why is the question out of scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method:

```
class ActionChainsChild(ActionChains):
   def move_by_offset(self, xoffset, yoffset):
        """
        Moving the mouse to an offset from current mouse position.

        :Args:
         - xoffset: X offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
         - yoffset: Y offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
        """
        if self._driver.w3c:
            self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_by(xoffset, yoffset)
            #self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()
        else:
            self._actions.append(lambda: self._driver.execute(
                Command.MOVE_TO, {
                    'xoffset': int(xoffset),
                    'yoffset': int(yoffset)}))
        return self
```

Practical links :

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.html

https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/