# Kill certain chrome process in python, not all

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
chrom_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrom_path)
link = 'https://google.com'
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
print((s.encode("utf-8")))
subprocess.call("TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROME.EXE")
subprocess.call("TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROMEDRIVER.EXE")
```

This code works good, but my code kills all chrome process not only this certain one. I want to kill only this chrome process that opens https://google.com

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: did you try suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/35286094/1358308

Comment: You could search by PID.  EG: `TASKLIST /FI "PID EQ 111"`  But `chrome.exe` will have multiple PIDs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty correct.

- `subprocess.call("TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROME.EXE")`: This line of code will kill all the running *chrome* processes.
- `subprocess.call("TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROMEDRIVER.EXE")`: This line of code will kill all the running *ChromeDriver* processes.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

---

It would be difficult to identify and kill only this [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) process that opens `https://google.com` that is being opened by the *ChromeDriver* because when automated tests are getting executed through *Google Chrome* you will observe that there are potentially dozens of Google Chrome processes running which can be observed through Windows Task Manager's Processes tab.

As per the article [Why Google Chrome Has So Many Processes](https://www.urtech.ca/2018/07/solved-why-google-chrome-has-so-many-processes/) for a better **user experience** *Google Chrome* initiates a lot of [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) background processes for each tab that have been opened by your *Automated Tests*.  Google tries to keep the browser stable by separating each web page into as many processes as it deems fit to ensure that if one process fails on a page, that particular process(es) can be terminated or refreshed without needing to kill or refresh the entire page.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)

So, retrieving a single *pid* and killing the only process won't help you.

---

As per the best practices your *test bed* should be:

- Configured with all the required *softwares*, *libraries* and *binaries*.
- *Test Execution* must be performed in a controled environment for optimized performance.
- While your `@Tests` are executing, it should be free from *Manual Intervention*.
- Particularly when your `@Tests` are *Selenium* based, while *test execution* is *InProgress* the *Test Environment* shouldn't be intervened.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Way to open Selenium browser not ovelapping my current browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162992/way-to-open-selenium-browser-not-ovelapping-my-current-browser/52164715#52164715)