# How to prevent selenium window from becoming an active one on session start?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Each time when a new selenium session starts the selenium window becomes active (front window). Is there any way to prevent this, so a new selenium window opens in the background?

Comment: Try headless options which will run in background.

Comment: @KajalKundu I know about this option. I need to keep the window open.

Comment: Ok got your question see the following stackoverfollow discussion if this help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background

Comment: @KajalKundu That‘s what I need. So my question is a duplicate.