# How to run a python script using selenium chromedriver in background (Windows)?

Tags: python, selenium, background, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a background web-crawler in python. I have managed to write the code for it and then I used the pythonw.exe app to execute it without any console window. Also, I ran ChromeDriver in headless mode.

The problem is, it still produces a console window for the ChromeDriver which says `$ DevTools listening on ...some address.`

How can I get rid of this window?

Comment: Look at [Can Selenium Webdriver open browser windows silently in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background) - seems helpful

Comment: You can silently run your chromedriver in background<br>
Check is the existing answer on it. [old-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you make the script as `.pyw`, when the new process `chromedriver.exe` is created, a console window appears for that. There is an option to turn on the option `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in **C#**, but there is not one yet in **Python** bindings for **selenium**. I was planning to fork selenium and add this feature myself.

## Solution for now (only for Windows): Edit the selenium library

Go to this folder: `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\` (The path till *Python38-32* depends on your installation of python).

There will be a file named `service.py`, which you need to edit as follows:

- Add the import statement at the top `from subprocess import STDOUT, CREATE_NO_WINDOW`
- Now (maybe in the line numbers 72 to 76), you must add another option `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in the function `subprocess.Popen()`. To make it clear, see before and after versions of code below:

**Before edit:**

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                stdout=self.log_file,
                                stderr=self.log_file,
                                stdin=PIPE)
```

**After edit:**

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                stdout=self.log_file,
                                stderr=self.log_file,
                                stdin=PIPE
                                creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW) # Here !
```

## Note:

Make a copy of the old `service.py` file, so that you replace it back if you need to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I modified selenium lib and was able to get rid of this window.

In my case, this is the modified file path:

C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py

Please see [modified section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8HXF.png)