# running webdriver selenium in background

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I looked up how can I run silently selenium:
[found the next great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-the-background)

I am trying to let selenium run regular until some action is completed and then run it in the background.

Is it possible?

thanx in advanced
Oz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not change actively running Selenium WebDriver session from normal to headless and vice versa.
In the similar manner you will not be able to re-define default downloading folder, `no-sandbox`, `disable-dev-shm-usage` etc.
All these parameters are loaded during the WebDriver object creating and can not be changed for existing, running WebDriver instance.