# Can Selenium Edge WebDriver open and switch to windows in the minimized state?

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, microsoft-edge

I don't want the `--headless` mode.

I use Python Selenium and Edge driver in Windows 11. My task requires to open and switch to many browser windows. And the browser will pop up from the background to the top of all windows in my system, even if I minimize it.

I hope that when I get a new URL and switch to it, selenium browser can be minimized and completed in the background. However, I still need the whole browser window, I don't want the `--headless` mode.

I have already seen this thread:
[can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-the-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-the-background)

I tried to minimize window, but the browser window will instantly appear and then minimize.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()
url = [...]
for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('', '_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
    driver.minimize_window() # however, still pop up
    # do something such as execute javascript or switch to iframes...
```

Is there a way to tell Selenium to open the windows in the minimized mode? Or dynamically determine whether `--headless`.

Besides, perhaps there are other good ways to complete my stupid circular task.

Comment: it's built on Chromium and at some point Chrome (or chromedriver?) changed so that it always comes to the front.  I haven't found a way around that except to use geckodriver/firefox.